# Are there reference managers which can develop/build library of references without importing/downloading PDF files in a personal collection?

Tags: citations, software, reference-managers

In a situation where one has PDFs which one would like to have a library of references for, I notice that reference management providers (specifically Mendeley and Endnote) require that these PDF files are downloaded/imported for the product to 'scan' the reference information and generate/populate references.

I find that this takes up desktop memory space, and I believe will contribute to the memory limits of my account with the provider.

Are there any reference managers that can build references from a collection of PDFs but do not have to download/import the PDF files per se?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm mostly familiar with JabRef, which is free and open-source and runs locally, so space constraints aren't an issue.  But it still offers the ability to 'import' documents and search online databases to fill in the information.  Would that work?